# useState() hook with initial value but its not reflected in the state variable

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, use-state

I have an object `myObj` which is a field of `data` object. I use `useState` hook to initiate a state variable with this object.

`myObj` is like `{"name": "John", "age": 20, ...}`.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const myComponent = ({data}) => {
   const[student, setStudent] = useState(data.myObj); // myObj is a object with value
    
    console.log(`${JSON.stringfy(student)}`); // it prints undefined, why?


    return (
        // here I need to render the student information but it is undefined.
     )
}
```

Do I mis-use the `useState` hook here? If so, how can I have the initial object value being reflected right after useState hook like showing in the console log above?

Answer (score 1):

The Issue here is your state is dependent on the props. But you need to check once whether this is needed, it might be needed if your state is a transformed value of your prop .

But if you are not doing much with your props, then you can safely remove it and consume the props directly and use it for rendering the elements . Because re-render in react is triggered even when the props of your component changes.

This article has a good explanation on why state dependent on props is not needed in most cases.[State Dependent on Props challenges](https://overreacted.io/writing-resilient-components/#dont-stop-the-data-flow-in-rendering)

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand, your state of `student` is not getting refreshed. If so, you have to use `useEffect` hook.

See, how?

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`${JSON.stringfy(student)}`);
}, [student])
```

In your case you are using `student` outside `return` block, that's why console is not getting printed. Using `useEffect` you will get update once it gets stored successfully.

If console is not important for you then you can directly print student's value without using `useEffect`,

```
return (
    <View>
        <Text>{student}</Text>
    </View>
)
```

Comment: Thanks. Interesting, your suggestion is exactly my code, but it doesn't print out student since it is undefined at the beginning. Let's forget about the console log thing.